# Golang bufio.Scanner: token too long

Tags: file, go, memory, error-handling, split

i have a big file (too big for memory), and i need to parse each record with the delimiter "|". The problem is, each record has a different size, thats why i always get the error "bufio.Scanner: token too long".

Is there any way, to retry the scan with a bigger buffersize, if i hit the bufio.Scanner: token too long error? Or is the bufio.Scanner not the right choice in my case, because i dont know the exact size of each record?

Thank you

https://go.dev/play/p/Erx15nXXCGk

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    // Example byte array
    byteArray := []byte("data1|data2|data3|data4|data5|data6|data7|data8|data9|data10")

    // Buffer size for reading chunks
    bufferSize := 6
    buf := make([]byte, bufferSize)

    // Create a bufio.Scanner with a custom split function
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(byteArray))
    scanner.Buffer(buf, bufferSize)
    scanner.Split(splitFunc)

    // Read the byte array in chunks
    for scanner.Scan() {
        // Process each token (chunk)
        chunk := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println("Chunk:", chunk, "Chunk Length:", len(chunk))
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        if err == bufio.ErrTooLong {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            fmt.Printf("Buffer size %d is too small...\n", bufferSize)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        }
    }
}

func splitFunc(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {

    // Return nothing if at end of file and no data passed
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    if i := strings.Index(string(data), "|"); i >= 0 {
        return i + 1, data[0:i], nil
    }

    // If at end of file with data return the data
    if atEOF {
        return len(data), data, nil
    }

    return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> scanner.Buffer(buf, bufferSize)
> ```

[You don't need to provide any buffer](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Buffer).

> By default, Scanner.Scan uses an internal buffer and sets the maximum token size to MaxScanTokenSize.

[If you simply remove it, the program works fine](https://go.dev/play/p/2zhw61uaiST).  You'll be subject to [MaxScanTokenSize](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#MaxScanTokenSize) which appears to be 64k.

Comment: Thanks, but in a real scenario I don't know the maximum length of the tokens I will read. So if the line is larger than 64k, I will still get the error message bufio.Scanner: token too long and the script aborts.

Comment: if the *token* is larger than 64k.   Not the entire line.  That's a pretty hefty token.  If you need larger, you can allocate your own buffer,  but you're going to have to decide its maximum capacity to be able to fit the largest token.  Probably, 64k will be more than enough for your data.